# How to show selective UI features?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, design-patterns

I have a UI that needs to either show icons on a timeline view or not  based on user profile. How can I show for some users and not for others? For example : the Sports Admin team needs to see the scores of all teams over time in the view (showing all years visually) but the players (when they login to the same web app) only see the timeline view with their team's performance over the years (not other details for a particular year). How can I achieve this? I am using Angular JS and javascript

I have looked into role based SSO login and show selectively and also cookies. My goal is faster performance - meaning the page needs to load fast.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate question, lacks some critical info and is confusingly written. However, this can likely be achieved by using the ngIf directive on the icons based on which user type is supposed to see them and $filter if the user is a player to format and reduce the data only relevant to the player. It would also be advisable that your backend foremost returns data only relevant to the user instead of returning every teams data as it would appear is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for the problem above that we have been facing. After many design sessions, the best approach was to have a "User Settings" link that would save the preferences at a backend database per user id that's already captured via SSO login. The backend returns data based on the user settings as the queries to get data from backend are now made dynamic to take the selections from User Settings into account while querying the backend. As a result the front end shows data specific to user.

Tested this and seems to work perfectly without any affecting any page load performance whatsoever.